# Code within pop-up does not affect worksheet elements

Tags: excel, vba, popup, commandbar

I am trying to create pop-up menu, that will give option to copy-paste a shape object out from shape group named "Element" (Oval + Text Box).
But it seemed that Select & Paste methods did not work.

```
Public Element_Menu As CommandBar

Function CreateSubMenu() As CommandBar

    Const pop_up_name = "pop-up menu"

    Dim the_command_bar As CommandBar
    Dim the_command_bar_control As CommandBarControl

    For Each menu_item In CommandBars
        If menu_item.Name = pop_up_name Then
            CommandBars(pop_up_name).Delete
        End If
    Next

    Set the_command_bar = CommandBars.Add(Name:=pop_up_name, Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=False)

    Set the_command_bar_control = the_command_bar.Controls.Add
    the_command_bar_control.Caption = "Add &Element"
    the_command_bar_control.OnAction = "AddElement"

    Set CreateSubMenu = the_command_bar

End Function

Sub ElementClick()

    Set Element_Menu = CreateSubMenu
    Element_Menu.ShowPopup

End Sub

Sub AddElement()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Element").Select 'Selecting template object to replicate
    ActiveSheet.Paste 'Inserting copy out from the clipboard 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the shape that is added correctly named "Element" (as per the line that does not work?)  It seems that it is called "Test Element".

Comment: Good point. Further, instead of hardcoding the name, use the`nam` variable.

Comment: I changed info about the problem. See initial message. The same result without any arguments in the Subroutine AddElement().

Comment: Sorry, without arguments (as it is now in the message above) the Macro is working!